# ¿Cómo acceder a una api levantada localmente en Windows desde MAC?

Tags: .net, api, localhost

Tengo una Api construida en `.net` Y una app realizada en `ReactJS`, ambas las levanto en mi maquina local con Windows y quisiera acceder a mi local en Windows desde mi Mac, he intentado acceder por medio de Hamachi, y logro acceder a la aplicación realizada en `ReactJS` pero no a la Api en .net. No tengo ningún tipo de respuesta más de la de tiempo de expiración ¿Cómo podría acceder también a la Api desde Mac para hacer peticiones? requiero alguna configuración o por dónde podría empezar a revisar porqué no logro realizar peticiones?

Anexo que ReactJS está en el puerto 3000 y la api en el puerto 44331

Comment: Comprobaste que el firewall de windows te permite escuchar en ese puerto, si no estas seguro, prueba desactivando el firewall, si te funciona activa el firewall nuevamente y añade la regla al firewall de windows

Comment: Deberás configurar el servicio *ASP.NET* con el archivo `launchSettings.json` que se crea con el mismo *scaffolding*. Ahí configuras el entorno de *launching* y en qué dirección escucha. Te recomiendo que uses [*Postman*](https://www.postman.com/), un *software* muy sencillo que permite realizar cualquier tipo de petición HTTP

Comment: Deberias dejar corriendo tu servicio en IIS sin tener que ejecutar el servicio desde visual y ahi podes habilitar puertos, protocolos, regla de firewall, etc.